# How to make comments Italic in gVim?

Tags: vim, comments, italics

I am fairly new to Vim and mainly use gVim for most of my coding purposes. I am trying to figure out what to add in my _vimrc (in windows) to make my comments italic.

I tried adding

```
highlight Comment cterm=italic
```

but that didn't work. My modifications so far in my vimrc (if it matters) is:

```
color slate
set number
set nowrap
set guioptions+=b
if has('gui_running')
  set guifont=Consolas:h10
endif
```

So what can I do so that my comments appear in italics (consolas, italic, size 10)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cterm` definition is only for high color terminals; for the GUI, you need to use the `gui=` argument:

```
highlight Comment cterm=italic gui=italic
```

Also, put this *after* the `:colorscheme` command in your `~/.vimrc`, or else it might get overridden.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it!

Comment: thanks @IngoKarkat, the `gui=italic` part also fixed it in neovim run by kitty. Even though it's still "terminal"